# In JavaFX, how to add a TextField in TableView that's inside a TabPane?

Tags: javafx

I've built this GUI so far using Scene Builder and I want to add empty rows (TextField) to TableView in each TabPane I made. Any help would be appreciated. Or if you can suggest an easier method of doing this task instead of JavaFX.

P.S. I'm new to progamming.
Thanks in advance.

[GUI so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne524.png)
[GUI so far (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXSPH.png)

My code so far

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Date;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Button button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("LOPA Software");

        window.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 500));
        window.show();
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.ContextMenuEvent;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    TreeView<String> treeView;

    @FXML
    TableView tableView;

    Image icon = new Image(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/icon.png"));
    private MouseEvent mouseEvent;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Project", new ImageView(icon));
        root.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem<String> compA = new TreeItem<>("Component A", new ImageView(icon));
        TreeItem<String> compB = new TreeItem<>("Component B", new ImageView(icon));
        TreeItem<String> compC = new TreeItem<>("Component C", new ImageView(icon));
        root.getChildren().addAll(compA, compB, compC);
        compA.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem<String> compA1 = new TreeItem<>("High", new ImageView(icon));
        TreeItem<String> compA2 = new TreeItem<>("Low", new ImageView(icon));
        compA.getChildren().addAll(compA1, compA2);

        treeView.setRoot(root);
    }


    public void mouseClick(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
            TreeItem<String> item = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(item.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <top>
      <VBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <MenuBar>
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cut" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
            <ToolBar>
              <items>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Toolbar" />
              </items>
            </ToolBar>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </top>
   <left>
      <TreeView fx:id="treeView" editable="true" onMouseClicked="#mouseClick" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <bottom>
      <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label text="Label" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <TabPane>
         <tabs>
            <Tab text="PHA">
               <content>
                  <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Cause" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Consequence" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Severity" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Likelihood" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Risk" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Safeguard" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Recommendation" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="LOPA" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="LOPA">
               <content>
                  <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Scenario" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Consequence">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Description" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Severity" />
                           </columns>
                        </TableColumn>
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Acceptable Risk Tolerance" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Initiating Events">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Description" />
                              <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Freq. (per year)" />
                           </columns>
                        </TableColumn>
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Independent Protection Layers (IPLs)" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Mitigated Cosequence" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Recommendation" />
                     </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </content>
            </Tab>
         </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: I'm confused. What are you asking? Empty rows are not the same as TextFields. You want to add text fields to your TableView? If so, that question has several answers around StackOverflow. If not, please clarify your goal.

Comment: Sorry for unclear description, yes I wanted to add textfields to tableview. But I have figured it out now. thanks for reply. Out of curiosity, is there a way to add empty rows?